# Alternate of String.subSequence from Index to Start and Ending Tags

Tags: java, string, substring, subsequence

I have a following set of Strings.

```
String s1 = "Some random text followed by timestamp('some data')";
String s2 = "Some extended random tet followed by timestamp('some extra data')";
String s3 = "Some tiny random text followed by timestamp('some tiny data')";
```

I want to replace the subSequence that starts with `timestamp('` and ends with `')`.
I know that the following `string.subSequence(beginIndex, endIndex)` will get you a subString from a string using the start and end tag. But in my case, I cannot just give it starting and ending indexes since it can be dynamic.

I am looking as something like this,

```
string.functionIAmLookingFor(String startCharSequence , String endCharSequence);
```

If both the charSequences are found in the String, either it returns the String that is in between starting and ending tags, or the String excluding this string, or any other format. I am using Java 7. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should have a look at [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)).

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) can solve this problem

Comment: @FlorentBayle : Thanks man, I feel stupid of not identifying it myself while i was too busy looking into some native function :)

Comment: @SergeyFedorov : thank u for the idea as well  but i try to dodge the Regular Expression bullet since it is overly complex most of the times. Thanks again though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give dynamic location using [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) and [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String))

```
int beginIndex = s1.indexOf("timestamp('");
int endIndex = s1.lastIndexOf("')");
s1 = s1.replace(s1.subSequence(beginIndex, endIndex), newValue);
```

Comment: Thanks , exactly what i was looking for.